# Bloc pattern does not show newly added user to sqflite on screen

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc, sqflite, stream-builder

I am using `sqflite` database to save user list.
I have user list screen, which shows list of user and it has a fab button,
on click of fab button, user is redirected to next screen where he can add new user to database.
The new user is properly inserted to the database
but when user presses back button and go backs to user list screen,
the newly added user is not visible on the screen.
I have to close the app and reopen it,then the newly added user is visible on the screen.

I am using `bloc` pattern and following is my code to show user list

```
class _UserListState extends State<UserList> {
  UserBloc userBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userBloc = BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context);
    userBloc.fetchUser();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    userBloc?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/detail");
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: userBloc.users,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<User>> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

          if (snapshot.data != null) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Dismissible(
                  key: Key(snapshot.data[index].id.toString()),
                  direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                  onDismissed: (direction) {
                    userBloc.deleteParticularUser(snapshot.data[index]);
                  },
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => UserDetail(
                               user: snapshot.data[index],
                              )));
                    },
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
                    subtitle:
                        Text("Mobile Number ${snapshot.data[index].userId}"),
                    trailing:
                        Text("User Id ${snapshot.data[index].mobileNumber}"),
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Following is my bloc code

```
    class UserBloc implements BlocBase {
  final _users = BehaviorSubject<List<User>>();

  Observable<List<User>> get users => _users.stream;

  fetchUser() async {
    await userRepository.initializeDatabase();

    final users = await userRepository.getUserList();
    _users.sink.add(users);
  }

  insertUser(String name,int id,int phoneNumber) async {
    userRepository.insertUser(User(id, name, phoneNumber));
    fetchUser();
  }

  updateUser(User user) async {
    userRepository.updateUser(user);
  }

  deleteParticularUser(User user) async {
    userRepository.deleteParticularUser(user);
  }

  deleteAllUser() {
    return userRepository.deleteAllUsers();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _users.close();
  }
}
```

As Remi posted answer saying i should try `BehaviorSubject` and `ReplaySubject` which i tried but it does not help. I have also called  `fetchUser();` inside `insertUser()` as pointed in comments

Following is the link of the full example

https://github.com/pritsawa/sqflite_example

Comment: Can you show your bloc?

Comment: @RémiRousselet I have added the code in the question, please have a look

Comment: First, as Remi said you should use a BehaviorSubject. The main problem you have is that after you insert the new user you don't update the users stream from the database. So, in the insertUser() method, besides the userRepository.insertUser() call you should also call fetchUser() to requery the database for the new list of stored users and update your users stream with new data.

Comment: @Luksprog i tried both BehaviourSubject and ReplaySubject and added fetchUser() inside insertUser(), but it still does not work. Whats the point of calling fetch user inside insertUser as i am inserting in completing different screen then too i tried your way but it does not work

Comment: I agree with @Luksprog, this should help

Comment: @KirillShashov tried it but does not work. Please have a look at my updated question. I tried Remi's and Luksprog's answer

Comment: *Whats the point of calling fetch user inside insertUser...* - the point is that after you insert an new user to also re query the database to get the new list of users. Without requerying the database the users stream can't really know that the database was updated(unless you have some sort of callback on the database?!). Are you sure you use the **same** UserBloc instance in both the user list and the details pages?

Comment: @GoFudgeYourSelves Did you try add `await` for `userRepository.insertUser` method call to be sure that `fetchUser` method is executed after insertion?

Comment: @KirillShashov tried adding await but does not help. I have added my repo link of github, if you have time please have a look

Comment: @Luksprog yeah i have only one bloc in my project. i have updated the question to update github link ,if you have time, please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow up from the comments, it seems you don't have a single instance of your UsersBloc in those two pages. Both the HomePage and UserDetails return a BlocProvider which instantiate a UsersBloc instance. Because you have two blocs instances(which you shouldn't have) you don't update the streams properly.

The solution is to remove the BlocProvider from those two pages(HomePage and UserDetail) and wrap the MaterialApp widget in it to make the same instance available to both pages.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      bloc: UserBloc(),
      child:MaterialApp(...
```

The HomePage will be:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return UserList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Remove the BlocProvider from UserDetail as well.
In the UsersBloc then call fetchUser() inside the insertUser() method after the user insertion, to requery the database and update the users stream.

Also as Rémi Rousselet said, use one of the subjects that return previous values.

Comment: this works even with PublishSubject. Thanks a lot for your time. Being a beginner in bloc i didn't knew that we should have only one instance of bloc to all pages if it is the same bloc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're using a `PublishSubject`.

When a new listener subscribes to a `PublishSubject`, it does not receive the previously sent value and will only receive the next events.

The easiest solution is to use a `BehaviorSubject` or a `ReplaySubject` instead. These two will directly call their listener with the latest values.

Comment: Does not work. I tried replacing PublishSubject with both BehaviorSubject  and ReplaySubject.

Comment: Have a look at my updated question. I tried your way but it does not help

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userBloc = BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context);
    userBloc.fetchUser();
  }
```

The problem is that you have called the userBloc.fetchUser() function in the initState of the page.

Bloc stream emits whenever a new data is added to it and the userBloc.fetchUser() function does exactly that, it adds the userList that you fetch from the Sqflite database.

Whenever you come back to the userlist screen from add user screen, init function is NOT called. It is only called when the userlist screen is created, that is, whenever you push it to the navigation stack.

The workaround is to call userBloc.fetchUser() whenever your StreamBuilder's snapshot data is null.

```
...
 if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      userBloc.fetchUser();
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
...
```